# What is the default DPI of HTC One (M8)?

Tags: htc-one-m8

I need to set my DPI back to default, but I never saved it. Does anyone know what the default DPI is for this device?

To clarify, PPI is pixels per inch, which is hardware-set, it's unchangeable. DPI is dots per inch and is what determines what scale of the elements on the screen, the manufacturer sets this by default, but I changed it with a root app and I want to know the original size without reflashing.

Comment: Did you change the density in build.prop? If not, then do `adb shell wm density reset` or use the density from `adb shell getprop ro.sf.lcd_density`.

Comment: @Firelord I used a root app to change it, so doing the second command with ADB tools will give me the default DPI before I changed it?

Comment: programming is correct, from gsmarena 1080 x 1920 pixels (~441 ppi pixel density)

Comment: @moonbutt74 I'm asking for the DPI though, not PPI. You can't change PPI, you can change DPI.

Comment: I really don't understand why I was downvoted... If someone could care to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to flash a 5.1 RUU for my phone anyway, so after doing so, I used Firelord's comment to get the correct answer to my question.

### **The default DPI for the HTC One (M8) is 480.**

Answer (score 0):

441 is the default dpi for HTC one m8

Comment: I think that's the PPI...

Comment: No it's dpi look at the link

Comment: It may say DPI, but I looked up the PPI and it said 441. They mistyped.

Comment: Well i saw it in YouTube video and other places to and they said the same thing. Dpi for HTC one m8 is 441.

Comment: Check this: http://www.technobuffalo.com/2015/03/01/htc-one-m9-vs-htc-one-m8-spec-shootout/ It says the PPI (pixels per inch) is 441. DPI is dots per inch, which means what scale everything is set on the screen, the manufacturer sets the DPI, but you can change it. I want to know what the manufacturer set it to.